# Validate time with am and pm using JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good with regex. I have the following time: `12:00am`.

I need a Javascript regex that respect this format: `hh:mm[am/pm]`

```
var regex = /^(\d\d):(\d\d)\s?(?:AM|PM)?$/;
```

Comment: I'd use HTML5 input validation (no regex needed) and post check the date serverside with `DateTime` methods.

Answer (score 9):

You are almost done, the missing part is about the tens which never be greater than 1 for the hours and 5 for the minutes. I have also added the "ignore case" flag at the end which accepts "am", "AM", "Am", "aM":

```
var regex = /^([0-1]\d):([0-5]\d)\s?(?:AM|PM)?$/i;
```

A bit more restrictive (1  ≤ hour ≤ 12):

```
/^([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)\s?(AM|PM)?$/i
```

Doc : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Comment: Another change I'd suggest is: `var regex = /^([0-1]\d):([0-5]\d)\s*(?:AM|PM)?$/i;`. Using \s* instead of \s? allows for any number of spaces

Comment: Here is your [regex in action](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=^%28[0-1]\d%29%3A%28[0-5]\d%29\s%3F%28%3F%3AAM|PM%29%3F%24&input=12%3A00%20AM).

Comment: @Grynn: Good point, I also used the same `\s?` only in my answer. (Note: Format provided by user in question has no spaces)

Comment: you can modify it for matching "06:00AM" or "6:00AM" like this

`/^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)\s?(AM|PM)?$/i`

Answer (score 4):

The below RegEx should work. [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/JKxCd/)

```
var regex = /^([0]\d|[1][0-2]):([0-5]\d)\s?(?:AM|PM)$/i;
/* The below lines are just for demo testing purpose */
var timeStr = ["13:59am","11:59AM","09:69PM", "09:24pm", "09:99pm", "15:23bm", "09:23 AM", "14:74 PM"];
for (i=0; i<timeStr.length; i++)
    console.log("Time String: "+timeStr[i]+ " Result: " +regex.test(timeStr[i]));
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

`([0]\d|[1][0-2])` - For Hours. Either `0` followed by any single digit (or) `1` followed by any single digit between `0-2` (that is, 0 or 1 or 2). This is to make sure that Hours value like 13 or 14 etc are treated as invalid (Since we are using time in AM/PM format, the Hours value should be a maximum of 12 only).

`([0-5]\d)` - For Minutes. Any single digit between `0-5` followed by another single digit between `0-9`. This is to make sure that minutes values like 64, 79 etc are treated as invalid.

`\s?` - 0 or 1 whitespace

`(?:AM|PM)$/i` - Case insensitive AM or PM (that is `am | pm | Am | Pm | aM | pM | AM | PM`)

**Console Output:**

```
Time String: 13:59am Result: false
Time String: 11:59AM Result: true
Time String: 09:69PM Result: false
Time String: 09:24pm Result: true
Time String: 09:99pm Result: false
Time String: 15:23bm Result: false
Time String: 09:23 AM Result: true
Time String: 14:74 PM Result: false
```

Comment: this will say `00:01 PM` is true. how to correct that ?

Answer (score 2):

The below works I tested it using RegExr
http://www.regexr.com/3btsp

`/^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)\s?(AM|PM)$/i`

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```